# How to use the TMR0 as a counter PIC16F84A in C ? Please, a code example

Tags: c, interrupt, pic, mplab

im using the 16F84A but i need the TMR0 as COUNTER not as TIMER , so i put the RA4 pin as Entry port..
the following put in the main section the binary value from 0 to 15 in 4 bits (led bar) every each 2 push in the RA4 botton while the TMR0 is usued as timer every second, its deploy every second in a 7 segment display the value from 0 to F, so i need to use the timer as counter, every 2 push in RA4 put the number in binary in the led bar)0000,0001,0101,............
please help

```
// CONFIG
#penter code hereragma config FOSC = XT        // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power-up Timer is enabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Code protection disabled)

#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void __interrupt() isr(void);
void Interrupcion_TMR0(void);//configuración de la interrupción

int cont=0;
int C=0;
int A=0;
int D=0;
void main(void) 
{
    
    TRISB=0b00000000;
    TRISA=0b00010000;
    
    Interrupcion_TMR0();//configuración de la interrupción
    
    while(1)
    {
        if(PORTAbits.RA4==0)
        {
            __delay_ms(250);
            A++;
                if(A==2)
                {
                    if(D<=16)
                    {
                    PORTA=D; 
                    D++;
                    A=0;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    D=0;
                    A=0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

void __interrupt() isr(void)//Función de interrupciones
{
    if(INTCONbits.T0IF==1)//Se comprueba la bandera
    {   
        INTCONbits.T0IF=0;  //Limpiamos la bandera de interrupción por INT
        TMR0=61;
        cont++;
        if(cont>=20)
        {    
            cont=0;
            switch(C)
            {
            case 0:
            PORTB=0b00111111;//Regresa con 0 en 7 segmentos 
            break;
            
            case 1:
            PORTB=0b00000110; //Regresa con 1 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 2:
            PORTB=0b01011011; //Regresa con 2 en 7 segmentos
            break;
             
            case 3:
            PORTB=0b01001111; //Regresa con 3 en 7 segmentos
            break;
             
            case 4:
            PORTB=0b01100110; //Regresa con 4 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 5:
            PORTB=0b01101101; //Regresa con 5 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 6:
            PORTB=0b01111101; //Regresa con 6 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 7:
            PORTB=0b00000111; //Regresa con 7 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 8:
            PORTB=0b01111111; //Regresa con 8 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 9:
            PORTB=0b01100111; //Regresa con 9 en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 10:
            PORTB=0b01110111; //Regresa con A en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 11:
            PORTB=0b01111100; //Regresa con B en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 12:
            PORTB=0b00111001; //Regresa con C en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 13:
            PORTB=0b01011110; //Regresa con D en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 14:
            PORTB=0b01111001; //Regresa con E en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            case 15:
            PORTB=0b01110001;//Regresa con E en 7 segmentos
            break;
            
            default:
            PORTB=0b00111111;//Regresa con 0 en 7 segmentos 
            C=0;
            break;
            
         } 
        C++;
        
        }
    }
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}

void Interrupcion_TMR0(void)//configuración de la interrupción
{
    OPTION_REGbits.PS0=1;
    OPTION_REGbits.PS1=1;
    OPTION_REGbits.PS2=1;
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA=0;    
    OPTION_REGbits.T0SE=0;
    OPTION_REGbits.T0CS=0;
    
    TMR0=61;
    cont=0;
    INTCONbits.T0IF=0;          //Se limpia la bandera
    INTCONbits.T0IE=1;          //Se habilita la interrupción
    INTCONbits.GIE=1;           //se habilita interrupción global
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. "Entry port" do you mean input port? Try to split requirements and problems in a bullet list. Be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the incrementing of the D value continues as long as the RA4 input is zero.

Modify the code to wait for the RA4 input to be one after each update of the D value.

Comment: It seems like he's using the negative logic. He applies 0 to the RA4 pin when the button is pressed and 1 when the button is unpressed.

Answer (score 0):

Oye amigo @Luisito! Hay te tengo mi propuesta...
First of all, I recommend you to use smaller data types than `int`, ie. `char` if you variable will not have a value greater than `127` or `unsigned char` if it will not have greater than `255`. Because these types are more 8-bit architecture friendly and don't consume that much RAM. Since the 16F84 has only 64 bytes of RAM, you can go out of RAM if don't use it thrifty.
Since you count only up to 16, a single byte type is more than enough for you.

### 7-Segment Display Code Definition

Let's begin by defining 7 segment convertion table with a preprocessor that controls the display type. Put this definition anywhere before main and other functions.

```c
#define DISPLAY_COMMON_ANODE 1
#define DISPLAY_COMMON_CATHODE 2

#define DISPLAY_TYPE DISPLAY_COMMON_CATHODE

// Let's make some preprocessor seven segment code definition
static const unsigned char BCDto7SegmentCode[] = {
#if DISPLAY_TYPE == DISPLAY_COMMON_CATHODE
    0x3F, 0x6, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0x7, 0x7F,
    0x6F, 0x77, 0x7C, 0x39, 0x5E, 0x79, 0x71, 0x40
#else
    0xC0, 0xF9, 0xA4, 0xB0, 0x99, 0x92, 0x82, 0xF8, 0x80,
    0x90, 0x88, 0x83, 0xC6, 0xA1, 0x86, 0x8E, 0xBF
#endif
};
```

This table is supposed to convert a BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) value to the approprite 7 segment code. And the `DISPLAY_TYPE` definition controls the definition blocks according to the defined type of display. Using a conversion table whic is based on an array like this is more speed efficient than the `switch-case` statements.

---

### Counting and Driving the Display

Since you have only 1 digit to drive you don't have to use a timer interrupt to update the display. Just update it whenever the display's backed value has changed. So I recommend you to get rid of all that interrupt stuff and make it simple as following.

```c
/**
 * Displays only the lower nibble.
 */
void displayOut(char value);

void main() {
    char counter = 0, pressCount = 0;

    TRISB=0b00000000;
    TRISA=0b00010000;

    // Display out the initial values once here
    displayOut(counter);

    while(1) {
        if(PORTAbits.RA4==0) {
            __delay_ms(250);
            pressCount++;
            if(pressCount >= 2) {
                pressCount == 0; // Reset the button press counter

                if(counter < 16) {
                    counter++;
                }
                else {
                    counter = 0; // Reset the counter
                }

                // After modifying the backing data we can now output the changed value
                displayOut(counter);
            }
        }
    }
}


void displayOut(char value) {
    // Mask and clear the upper nibble garbage if any
    value &= 0xF;
    // Output the value as binary to the PORTA
    PORTA &= 0xF0; // Clear Low nibble on PORTA first
    PORTA |= value; // Only low nibble to print
    // Convert the value to 7-seg code and than output it to the PORTB
    PORTB = BCDto7SegmentCode[value];
}
```

As you can see I manage counting the button and display value by using only 2 bytes. However you've used 4 `int` variables each of which occupies 2 bytes and in total 2 x 4 = 8 bytes. Memory usage needs more care in tiny embedded microcontrollers.